# Prevent less time in angular js web application

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have collected all records from angular js batarang but, I don't know how to prevent less time in loading sites and how to know about which range of watcher is correct. Please help me to find this.

Thank you.

Comment: A common cause is using ng-repeat with long arrays; if this is your case, you can use pagination (make use of limitTo or otherwise).

Comment: For Angular 2+ use [tag:angular], for angular 1.x use [tag:angularjs]. This question looks like it is angularjs, if you could remove the `angular` tag :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally 2000 watchers are considered OK per controller. If your watchers count is going above that try to minimize the watchers.

Keeping watchers under limit reduces the time consumed by `$digest` and `$apply` cycles and your application remains smooth and responsive.

- Watchers are used to track variables defined with `$scope`. So, use `$scope` for variables that are going to be used in `View` or variables were two way binding is required. If you are storing temporary result or variables (that are not going to be changed) use simple JavaScript variables with var.
- If your controller is large try to divide the same functionality into 2-3 separate controllers to reduce the `watchers` at a particular screen.
- Use `ng-repeat` with `limit` for large arrays.